# Having Trouble to deploy a Rails App to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I'm having trouble to deploy a rails app to Heroku. Heroku is giving me the Error Message `An error occurred while installing Ruby ruby-2.1.1` which is confusing me after all that I've done to set everything to ruby 2.0.0.
Any Ideas? Thanks!

My Steps so far:

- I searched here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes for a ruby version that is currently compatible.
- I Installed the Version Ruby 2.0.0 via RVM on my Computer
- I made sure that this version is used: `rvm use ruby-2.0.0`
- I added the line ruby '2.0.0' to the App's Gemfile
- I did run `bundle install` (No Error Messages)
- I did run `git push heroku master`

The Heroku Errormessage:

```
   > ~/Desktop/blog(heroku_deploy) git push heroku master
Counting objects: 61, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Writing objects: 100% (61/61), 14.77 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 61 (delta 26), reused 41 (delta 7)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Removing .DS_Store files
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing Ruby ruby-2.1.1
remote:  !     For supported Ruby versions see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     Note: Only the most recent version of Ruby 2.1 is supported on Cedar-14
remote:  !     Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl --fail --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.1.1.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to quiet-springs-8925.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/quiet-springs-8925.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/quiet-springs-8925.git'
```

The Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support Ruby 2.1.1. Like it says in the errors, you can find which ruby runtimes work [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes).

Quick look at the Ruby runtimes that work gives: 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0.0, 2.1.6, 2.2.2.

Comment: sorry i typed the wrong version number, just edited this post, i used ruby 2.0.0, so a Version that Heroku should support.

Comment: But you also quote did this: "I made shure that this version is used: rvm use ruby-2.1.4." So rather try: `rvm use ruby-2.0.0`

Comment: thanks, this was not edited jet, i've alredy tried  rvm use ruby-2.0.0

Comment: I made a stupid mistake and found the problem. I was editing a different version the whole time, the master was indeed on ruby 2.1.1. thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you could mark it correct, so others can see this as a proper answer that'd be great.